# Windows 11 ARM Copilot on macOS with Parallels?

Tags: macos, windows-11, parallels

Has anyone been able to get Windows 11 Copilot working on Windows 11 ARM in Parallels on macOS?

I have the correct version of Windows 11, but no success so far.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have.
[Windows 11 in Parallels ARM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmVNF.jpg)

Didn't receive the update in my M1 Pr Macbook Pro though.

Comment: I just got it to run on my other Mac. Follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88ykYUZP8xU